# Why does java tzupdater add leap seconds?

Tags: java, date, datetime, time, leap-second

There are some references mentioned that leap seconds are ignored by Java:

[How can a 1 year old (java) lib correctly perform an UTC Time formatting, considering a newly introduced leap second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21782785/how-can-a-1-year-old-java-lib-correctly-perform-an-utc-time-formatting-consid)

[Do Java system milliseconds take account of leap seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022346/do-java-system-milliseconds-take-account-of-leap-seconds)

[JDK-4272347 : (cal/tz) support leap seconds ticket](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4272347)

Yet the document [Timezone Data Versions in the JRE Software](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html) mentions:

> New leap second 2015-06-30 23:59:60 UTC as per IERS Bulletin C 49.

3rd party Java library Time4J uses it's own list of leap seconds.

Why does java's tzupdater tool add leap seconds if they are ignored by Java?

Comment: Why do you think that tzupdater adds leap seconds?

Comment: David, as I understand, the latest tzupdater based on tzdata2015a adds leap second: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html

Comment: Good question, but I think it is just a copy-and-paste action in release-notes of tzupdater. The TZDB-maintainers have this entry in their release notes, and Oracle just copies it (but NOT the leap second data!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now closely looked at the release-notes of TZUPDATER and IANA (in its experimental location github/eggert/tz):

**TZUPDATER says:**

> The Mexican state of Quintana Roo, represented by America/Cancun, will
>   shift from Central Time with DST to Eastern Time without DST on
>   2015-02-01 at 02:00.  Chile will not change clocks in April or
>   thereafter; its new standard time will be its old daylight saving
>   time. This affects America/Santiago, Pacific/Easter, and
>   Antarctica/Palmer.  New leap second 2015-06-30 23:59:60 UTC as per
>   IERS Bulletin C 49.

**IANA says:**

> Release 2015a - 2015-01-29 22:35:20 -0800
>
> ```
>  Changes affecting future time stamps 
>
>  The Mexican state of Quintana Roo, represented by America/Cancun, 
>  will shift from Central Time with DST to Eastern Time without DST 
>  on 2015-02-01 at 02:00.  (Thanks to Steffen Thorsen and Gwillim Law.) 
>
>  Chile will not change clocks in April or thereafter; its new standard time 
>  will be its old daylight saving time.  This affects America/Santiago, 
>  Pacific/Easter, and Antarctica/Palmer.  (Thanks to Juan Correa.) 
>
>
>  New leap second 2015-06-30 23:59:60 UTC as per IERS Bulletin C 49. 
>  (Thanks to Tim Parenti.)
> ```

From this it is most probable that an Oracle-employee has just done **copy-and-paste without thinking much about the content if it is really relevant for the Java-distribution**. The only change was removing the author references. Of course, the fact remains that in actual OpenJDK- and Oracle-Java-distributions there is no code or location which could load such leap second data.

In my own answer to this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065355/are-leap-seconds-catered-for-by-calendar) I have also pointed to the newest related [mail statement](https://github.com/threeten/threeten/issues/197) where the Threeten project leaders finally dropped a temporarily available planned support for leap seconds. So your optimism regarding Java-8 is not justified.

By the way, the newest version v2.3 of Time4J can now deploy the leap second informations contained in the IANA-TZDB as you have this expected from TZUPDATER-tool.

Comment: There is a good explanation about TZUpdater 2.0 at https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/understanding_time_zone_updater_2

Comment: @Costlow It is really astonishing that Oracle has even given the meaningless advice to update the tz repository using TZUpdater 2.0 for help about leap second, see [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/the_2015_leap_second_s). It seems not everyone at Oracle is really involved in the matter. They have even pointed to the wrong statement of Java-API speaking about possible second values in the range 0-61 (the value 61 is impossible!).