# Java time ahead of linux time (leap second)

Tags: java, linux, leap-second

I have changed the Linux system date to Sat Jun 30 23:50:00 2012.
After changing the date I am running a simple java program to log the system date. 
The problem is: Java is logging 25 seconds ahead of Linux system time. 
For example:
Java log: 2012-07-01 00:02:15 INFO  Scheduler:19 - Sun Jul 01 00:02:15 GMT 2012
Linux time: Sun Jul  1 00:01:50 GMT 2012
Both are GMT!

I am doing this to analyze the leap second issue.
I checked total no of leap second in /etc/localtime it is 25.
zdump -v /etc/localtime | grep 59:60 | wc -l
25

I rebooted the system and also restarted the ntp server but still there is 25 second difference!

I am using SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP3  (x86_64) and JAVA 1.7

Please help me out to understand what is wrong? And how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your timezone data in JRE:

- Download Oracle `tzupdater` from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/tzupdater-download-513681.html
- Note 2015a update includes fix for `New leap second 2015-06-30 23:59:60 UTC as per IERS Bulletin C 49`
- run it: `java -jar tzupdater.jar`

Comment: I tried the above option but still I am getting the same issue! Java time in milliseconds is same as Unix time in milliseconds. But the new Date() in java is showing 25 seconds more! When i change the time zone to UTC, everything works fine. (I checked UTC there is no leap second present)

Comment: and which timezone do you experience issue with?

Comment: I am facing issue with GMT timezone.

Comment: Oracle does not deploy the leap second infos contained in TZDB so the suggested procedure is completely useless even if Oracle blindly copies the TZDB-news into its own announcements of TZ-Updater-versions. See also this [SO-post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28918934/2491410).